# Passing driver instance to another class with constructor

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am passing a `WebDriver` instance to the class below as

```
FunctionalComponents fc = new FunctionalComponents(driver)
```

from another class, but the object creation happens before constructor is executed. As it is, the objects created are having `null` value in the driver instance.

How can I solve this problem?

```
public class FunctionalComponents  
{    
    public FunctionalComponents(WebDriver driver) 
    {
        this.driver = driver;                            
    }

    CaptureElement element= new CaptureElement(driver);

    public void Method()
    {
        // method logic
        // i call object element here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don’t set the value of your member variable outside during the field definition. Do it from within the constructor, which will guarantee the population of the variables as you’d like. To wit:

```
public class FunctionalComponents  
{
    private IWebDriver driver;
    private CaptureElement element;

    public FunctionalComponents(WebDriver driver) 
    {
        this.driver = driver;
        this.element = new CaptureElement(driver);
    }

    public void Method()
    {
        // method logic
        // i call object element here
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Jim, you haven't declared the `driver` instance in the FunctionalComponents class. I think you meant to add `private WebDriver driver;`? Otherwise `this.driver` is going to fail... well it won't compile but you know what I mean.

Comment: Neither will the original poster’s code, for the same reason. :) Of course, you’re right, but I was really just trying to demonstrate the solution. Edited answer to fix.